# How to combine three different DC voltages from solar arrays with voltages up to 360 V into one DC voltage for input into an inverter?

Tags: voltage, current, solar-energy

Possible solution:

- Convert each DC input into high frequency AC.
- Connect each AC voltage onto a separate primary winding of a toroidal transformer with one secondary winding.
- Supply to each primary winding to be in phase with each other
- The total primary to secondary ratio being 3:1 to give an output of maximum 360 V AC.
- Convert output back to DC for inverter input.

Is this feasible?

Comment: 3 blocking diodes may be easier.

Comment: Does it really need to be a "torrid" transformer? I can't even think of a reason why a toroidal transformer would be necessary, let alone a "torrid" one ...

Comment: Drat that spell checker!

Comment: No, it's definitely **not feasible** how you described it.

Comment: Buy a 3-string solar inverter, you need the separate maximum power point trackers.

Answer (score 3):

If there are three different solar arrays with different size, each array has a different optimal voltage and current for maximum power output. So each array needs its own inverter to find the individual maximum power point.

If the arrays are connected in parallel with blocking diodes, it is possible that only the array with the highest voltage will be used if the arrays are too different.

Only if three identical arrays with the same orientation to the Sun are connected in parallel with blocking diodes a common voltage allows equal currents for all three arrays. Only then each array will produce the same power.

If one of the arrays is shaded by a tree or a house, only the two other arrays deliver power to the inverter.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a bad plan.

Your core idea is absolutely correct: Convert the disparate sources and **Couple** them by bringing them to a "common, bus" voltage/frequency/phase-sync, and from there, convert to final output.   Nothing wrong with that.

However, you are staggeringly increasing the difficulty level by making that coupling voltage AC.  That voltage should be DC, to cross off needs to generate a sinewave or sync up - syncing particularly is a really hard problem, and there *aren't* easy off-the-shelf solutions to it.  And, as you observe in your step 5, the inverter is going to run off of DC *anyway*, so that's your coupling voltage right there.

In other words, **don't make it harder than it is :)**

But let's head a few things off at the pass.

##### "But I need to transmit power long distances!"

OK, but solve that problem *separately* and on a per-array basis.  I agree, a 12V coupling voltage would be ill-suited for a 20 metre cable run.  But for instance if your series panel voltage is 70 volts DC, that's fine for a 20m cable run.

And don't be bashful about wire size - if you have a problem that can be solved by fat wires, do it - just use aluminum wires. *And it really helps to switch "parts bins" from the electronic to the AC mains electrical supply (e.g. the guys who wire houses).  For instance  I've seen many Youtube homesteaders fail off-grid power setups because they bought vehicle-tier 10 AWG copper, because the correct 2 AWG copper was prohibitive.  *Well, heck*.  The correct aluminum is 0 AWG, and that's the same price as the 10 AWG copper!  So the fails were totally *unnecessary*.

##### Don't fall into a fallacy of not needing a battery.

If you are generating to serve off-grid loads, realistically you will need a battery. It's optimistic to think otherwise. A lot of novices approach solar and think "why not?" and the answer is lots of things - at the very least line stability when a cloud rolls over.

But it doesn't have to be a gigantic battery.  Size it to your desires, but it is really there to carry over irregular/peak loads. It should be able to handle inverter current peaks when solar is momentarily out.

##### A note for if this system is grid-tied.

If this system is only to generate solar to sell back to the AC mains electric grid, then **forget coupling altogether**.  Your coupling voltage *is* the AC mains power grid.  If you have 3 solar arrays to sync in 3 different locations, you have 3 grid-tie inverters in 3 different locations. Easy peasy.

It's a lot easier and safer to use gold-standard Code legal methods to extend utility-supplied power in the usual an ordinary way any electrician will recognize and any local inspector will approve.   For instance if one solar array is 700' from your home, then bury cheap commodity aluminum 2-2-2-4 MH feeder or pole line quadplex, out to the solar site. Fit a subpanel there, all generic Codebook stuff, easily approved. Then next to the subpanel, fit the grid-tie inverter. Done and dusted!